# plot() function in MATLAB returning solid figure instead of boundary

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm new to MATLAB and trying to recreate shapes and images from their x,y coordinates using the plot() function, as follows:

```
handle = plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),color,'LineWidth',line_width)
```

where 'shape' is a list of x, y coordinates of the figure.
Instead of getting a just the boundary/edges (which are represented by the x, y coordinates), like so:

[image: boundary]

I get a plot where all the points are joined, like so:

[image: filled].

I have tried using `scatter()` instead, but a scatter plot is not useful for what I eventually want to do. Is there a way to get the `plot()` function to not join all points the way it is doing right now?

Comment: what is the ordering of your points in `shape`? Is it following the edges or is it mixed? It looks like if it is drawing lines from the top to the bottom. Zoom into you plot and have a look how the points are connected

Comment: The issue is indeed the ordering. This will connect the points in order, but it seems that after they are not in your case, and you are connecting from top to bottom multiple times, like a sawtooth signal

Comment: The ordering of the points is important. If you are trying to plot simple shapes, check the Matlab documentation on [inserting shapes in images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html).

Comment: Try plotting without a line, you should see that as a scatter the points are correct, and as previous comments have said it appears filled because of the order the points are joined. i.e. `handle = plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),color,'LineStyle','none','Marker','.')`